# Will I be able to build GUI-based desktop applications in the Visual Studio 2015 Express for Windows Desktop Edition?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Will I be able to build GUI-based desktop applications in the Visual Studio 2015 Express for Windows Desktop Edition or do I need the professional version for that?

Comment: Depends on what framework you want to use for it

Comment: Yes, you will be able. But why did not try it first and then asking?

Comment: Just basic windowed applications with buttons and stuff like that.

Comment: Why do you think it's called Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop?

Comment: How do I know? Maybe it's only for console applications.

Comment: Use Community Edition if you need free IDE for desktop development

Comment: @MikhailR. How do you know? Why not try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on notes provide on following MSDN article it looks like you can

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj153219.aspx

*This walkthrough is based on Visual Studio Professional, which offers the WPF Application template on which you'll build the project for this walkthrough. **Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop also offers that template**, but Visual Studio Express for Windows and Visual Studio Express for Web don't. For introductory information about how to use Visual Studio Express for Windows...*

Hope this helps you